# Swift Admob Console isn't displaying device test ID?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, admob

I've implemented Admob into my project however I can't add the test device for my iPhone.

Here is the code:

```
 let request = GADRequest()
    request.testDevices = [kGADSimulatorID, "XXXXX"]
    myAd = GADInterstitial(adUnitID: "ca-app-pub-4411736350819540/1731977917")
    myAd.delegate = self
    myAd.load(request)
```

My device ID isn't showing in the console when I run the app, it just shows an actual ad and not a test ad.

It works fine in Simulator.

Is the iPhone device ID meant to be the UDID found in iTunes?

When I comment out the testDevices line this is what the console shows:

```
2017-04-20 01:57:57.311 SpaceShip[2798:] <FIRAnalytics/INFO> Firebase Analytics v.3600000 started
2017-04-20 01:57:57.392 SpaceShip[2798:] <FIRAnalytics/INFO> To enable debug logging set the following application argument: -FIRAnalyticsDebugEnabled 
2017-04-20 01:57:57.398: <FIRInstanceID/WARNING> FIRInstanceID AppDelegate proxy enabled, will swizzle app delegate remote notification handlers. To disable add "FirebaseAppDelegateProxyEnabled" to your Info.plist and set it to NO
2017-04-20 01:57:57.397 SpaceShip[2798:] <FIRAnalytics/INFO> Successfully created Firebase Analytics App Delegate Proxy automatically. To disable the proxy, set the flag FirebaseAppDelegateProxyEnabled to NO in the Info.plist
true
2017-04-20 01:58:05.367 SpaceShip[2798:] <FIRAnalytics/INFO> Firebase Analytics enabled
```

Answer (score 0):

Your test ID is not being printed in the console because you've already set your test ID with:

```
request.testDevices = [kGADSimulatorID, "XXXXX"] // It thinks "XXXXX" is your test ID
```

Comment out that from your `request`:

```
let request = GADRequest()
// request.testDevices = [kGADSimulatorID, "XXXXX"]
myAd = GADInterstitial(adUnitID: "ca-app-pub-4411736350819540/1731977917")
myAd.delegate = self
myAd.load(request)
```

After you comment it out run your application again. The test ID should now be in your console.

Once you have your test ID, uncomment `request.testDevices`, and then replace `XXXXX` with your test ID.

```
let request = GADRequest()
request.testDevices = [kGADSimulatorID, "XXXXX"]
myAd = GADInterstitial(adUnitID: "ca-app-pub-4411736350819540/1731977917")
myAd.delegate = self
myAd.load(request)
```

Comment: Unfortunately I don't get anything related to device ID. I've added the log in the original question

Comment: This works fine for the simulator. It says " To get test ads on this device, call: request.testDevices = @[ kGADSimulatorID ];" It just doesn't work on my device